# How to get a query response time on Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Please, how can I do to get the response time when executing eloquent query ? 
for example:

```
$arf = App\Roles::where('description','test')->get()
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you need use any profier for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel itself define a `microtime` in `index.php`

```php
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
```

So you should do the same after the query and calculate the difference

```
$begin = microtime(true);
$arf = App\Roles::where('description','test')->get();
$end = microtime(true) - $begin;
```

Now `$end` is the response time

> Comparing against the globally defined microtime may not be accurate as HTTP requests go through a pipeline to reach the query

You can also listen to query events and access the time

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/database#listening-for-query-events)

```php
\DB::listen(function ($query) {
      info('Query took ' . $query->time);
});
```

And that is coming from `Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted` [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Events/QueryExecuted.php#L26)

```php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Database\Events;

class QueryExecuted
{
    /**
     * The SQL query that was executed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $sql;

    /**
     * The array of query bindings.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $bindings;

    /**
     * The number of milliseconds it took to execute the query.
     *
     * @var float
     */
    public $time;

    /**
     * The database connection instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\Connection
     */
    public $connection;

    /**
     * The database connection name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $connectionName;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $sql
     * @param  array  $bindings
     * @param  float|null  $time
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Connection  $connection
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($sql, $bindings, $time, $connection)
    {
        $this->sql = $sql;
        $this->time = $time;
        $this->bindings = $bindings;
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->connectionName = $connection->getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially use the query log.

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
// ... query
dump(DB::getQueryLog());
```

The log should include the times for the queries.

Comment: I've been around for a long time :)

Answer (score 0):

Query Execution

```
\Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {          
            $sql = $query->sql; 
            $time = $query->time;
            $connection = $query->connection->getName();
 
            Log::debug('query : '.$sql);
            Log::debug('time '.$time);
            Log::debug('connection '.$connection);
        });
```

Query

```
StaffRegister::all();
```

Output

```
[2021-03-14 08:00:57] local.DEBUG: query : select * from `staff_registers`  
[2021-03-14 08:00:57] local.DEBUG: time 0.93  
[2021-03-14 08:00:57] local.DEBUG: connection mysql
```

complete structure

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Models\StaffRegister;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
   
       \Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {
      
           $sql = $query->sql; 
           $time = $query->time;
           $connection = $query->connection->getName();

           Log::debug('query : '.$sql);
           Log::debug('time '.$time);
           Log::debug('connection '.$connection);
       });

       $obj = StaffRegister::all(); 
    
       return $obj;
   }
}
```